# SQL query below returns null - JAVA gui

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface

I am trying to create a swing application with vendor databases. Howewer SQL query below returns null for some reason. This query should create a vendor account if VAT number is not found in the database. What could be the reason behind this error?

My code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        String vName = vendorField.getText();
        String adress = adressField.getText();
        String country = (String) countryField.getSelectedItem();
        String vat = vatField.getText();
        String pTerms = ptermsField.getText();
        String iban = ibanField.getText();
        String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/masterdata_db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet;

        String check = "SELECT * FROM vendorcreation WHERE VAT = '"+vatField.getText()+"'";      
        resultSet = st.executeQuery(check);

        boolean status = true;

        if(resultSet.next()!=status){
            String sql1 = "INSERT INTO vendorcreation"
                    + "(VendorName, Adress, VAT, PaymentTerms, IBAN, Country) VALUES"
                    + "(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pSt2=conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            pSt2.setString(1, vName);
            pSt2.setString(2, adress);    
            pSt2.setString(3, vat);
            pSt2.setString(4, pTerms);    
            pSt2.setString(5, iban);  
            pSt2.setString(6, country);   

            pSt2.executeUpdate(sql1);  
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "VENDOR ACCOUNT CREATED!");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "VENDOR ALREADY EXISTS!", "Inane error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        System.err.println("AN ERROR OCCURRED! PLEASE CONTACT YOUR SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR.");
        System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: *SQL query below returns null* what exactly does that mean?

Comment: In console I get "NULL" value as an error message.

Comment: Replace your useless message by `e1.printStackTrace()`, and you'll know what the actual problem is. (There is a huge difference between printing something, and returning something. Use the appropriate terminology. And please, use prepared statements to pass parameters to a query, instead of concatenation).

Answer (score -1):

Change "=" to "LIKE" in select statement,

```
String check = "SELECT * FROM vendorcreation WHERE VAT LIKE '"+vatField.getText()+"'";
```

Comment: Unfortunaltely still receive the same error upon changing to LIKE.